# Get column name by rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that was created importing data from an Excel spreadsheet. The table currently looks like this:
[image]

I would like to either retrieve the column name from every row or either create a new table with a couple of columns, Data and ColumnName

So, being more clear, ABAS-3 for example is under ClinicalPsycology column, I'd like to create a temporary table or at least return in a query the column name for ABAS-3.

The ideal for me would be to create a temporary table that looks like this:

```
     Data      ColumnName
---------------------------
    ABAS-3    ClinicalPsycology
    ADHDT-2   ClinicalPsycology
    AAB       SpecialEducation
    SAGES-3   Counseling
```

... and like that.. is that possible?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @I'm using SQL Server, I believe I'm just going to modify the Excel file and import it again lol, thank you!

Comment: Which dbms do you use? sql-server, oracle, MySql,...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general way to do this in any database is to use `union all`:

```
select ClinicalPsycology as data, 'ClinicalPsycology' as column
from t
union all
select SpecialEducation as data, 'SpecialEducation' as column
from t
union all
. . .;
```

Some databases support lateral joins (via the `lateral` or `apply` keywords).  Such methods would be more efficient than using `union all` on each column.